# WPF BasedOn Style with Style.Resources

Tags: wpf, dictionary, resources, styles

Hi there, I'm asking for your help, as I can't get my 'BasedOn' style to work properly. Here is the situation :

I have my base style defined in a ResourceDictionary, like this :

> Styles.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}" x:Key="MyBaseStyle">
<Style.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ...>
        ...
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate ...>
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        ...
    </Style>
</Style.Resources>
<!-- This is for test purpose -->
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
```

I merge this dictionary in my App.xaml like this :

> App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is what I've done before, that worked perfectly, in my main window :

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<TreeView ... Style="{StaticResource MyBaseStyle}" />
```

But because I have multiple TreeViews in my application, I need to apply MyBaseStyle to them, and add a DataTrigger different for each TreeView. I tried this :

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<TreeView ...>
    <TreeView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyBaseStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- DataTrigger here -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Style>
</TreeView>
```

The problem is that the HierarchicalDataTemplate in MyBaseStyle is not working. The Red background of MyBaseStyle appears, and the DataTrigger works fine, but not the template. It seems like the program is ignoring the Style.Resources of the BasedOn style ??

I think it could be a style scope problem, but how can I solve it, without having to repeat code for every TreeView ? Someone has already been in this situation, and know the cause of the problem ?

Thank you for your help,
Arnaud.

Comment: What if you moved the `Style` from ` <TreeView.Style>` to ` <TreeView.Resources>`

Comment: Nice try, but it still doesn't work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.
For those interested, here are the details.

Instead of using a Style with Style.Resources, I set the ItemTemplateSelector property for each TreeView :

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="..." ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" />
...
<TreeView x:Name="treeView2" ItemsSource="..." ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}" />
```

that is present in the window resources :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Selector x:Key="selector" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and implemented like this :

```
public class Selector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is TreeDirectory) return Application.Current.FindResource("dirTemplate") as HierarchicalDataTemplate;
        if (item is TreeFile) return Application.Current.FindResource("fileTemplate") as HierarchicalDataTemplate;
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

The selector returns a HierarchicalDataTemplate, depending on the type of the item. These templates are located (in this case) in the Application resources :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="dirTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:TreeDirectory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="fileTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:TreeFile}">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```